# How to get mean from list that is partially empty example [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]

Tags: python, mean

How to get mean from list that is partially empty example `[0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]`

So mean should be `(2+4+4+10)/4 = 5` , but `statistics.mean()` divides by the overall amount of numbers in the list (which in this case is 10).

So in my case I need to get mean from the list of numbers which are divisible by 3 (list b)

```
import random
import statistics

a = []
b = []
c = [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]
for x in range (10):
    a.append(random.randint(0,101))

for x in a:
    if x%3==0:
        b.append(x)
    else:
        b.append(0)

average = statistics.mean(b)

print('a',a)
print('b',b)
print('Srednia',average)
```

Comment: From `c = [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]`, you can get a list of non-zero elements with `[i for i in c if i]`. It would return `[2,4,4,10]`

Comment: The list isn't partially empty. It makes a big difference to your average note if you got `[80, 100]` or `[80, 100, 0, 0, 0]`!

Comment: the question doesn't ask to filter if empty, but if non-multiple of 3... I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out the zeros from the list using a for-loop perhaps

```
from statistics import mean

c = [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]

#Filter out 0's
non_zero_c = [item for item in c if item]

#Calculate mean from non zero numbers
print(mean(non_zero_c))
```

The output will be `5`

Answer (score 0):

Very quickly, the easiest way is to use some list comprehension to select the part of the list that interest you.

Example:

"How to get mean from list that is partially empty example [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10] "

```
a = [0,2,4,0,4,0,0,0,0,10]
a_selection = [elt for elt in a if elt != 0]
m = sum(a_selection)/len(a_selection)
```

Same for divisible by 3:

```
b_selected = [elt for elt in b if elt%3==0]
```

Comment: Should be /len(a_selection).

Comment: @westgarthw correct

Answer (score 0):

In alternative to creating a list of only non-zero elements you can count them

```
non_zero_mean = sum(x) / sum(element != 0 for element in x)
```

here I'm using the "trick" that from a math point of view in Python (like in C and C++) `True == 1` and `False == 0`.

Another alternative is

```
non_zero_mean = sum(x) / (len(x) - x.count(0))
```